# Adding Dynamic Account Links to homepage

Tags: dynamic, authentication, hyperlink, logout, business-catalyst

I'm looking to add (what I call, might go by another name) Dynamic Account Links to my website, so when the user is logged out, the link would say "Sign In" and then "Sign Out" when the user is logged in.

I figured I'd put the Register link on the Sign In page.

I'm using Adobe Business Catalyst.

I've found related questions on here but they all seem to relate to Ruby and Magento.

Could anyone shed some light on this matter?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Liquid Markup enabled, you can serve just the correct html like this:

```
{% if globals.user.isLoggedIn -%}
    ...Sign Out link...

{% else -%}
    ...Sign In link...

{% endif -%}
```

---

Without Liquid Markup, you'll need to get CSS involved:

```
<div class="visible-iff-true--{module_isloggedin}">
    ...Sign Out link...
</div>

<div class="visible-iff-false--{module_isloggedin}">
    ...Sign In link...
</div>
```

```css
.visible-iff-true--0,
.visible-iff-false--1 {
    display: none;
}

.visible-iff-true--1,
.visible-iff-false--0 {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, however, the Liquid doesn't seem to process properly as it's simply showing the raw code on the frontend. You can see the image here [link](http://i.imgur.com/zAAGFvG.png)] and the code I entered was `{% if
                  globals.user.isLoggedIn - %}<a href="/account/sign-out">Sign Out</a>
                  {% else -%} <a href="/account/sign-in">Sign In</a>
                  {% endif -%}`. Many thanks.

Comment: Try placing just `{{ this | json }}` on the page. If it does not render a block of JSON, then your site does not have Liquid enabled (or the code is not in a file that BC considers to be a 'page').

Comment: Huh, well that produced a lot stuff [link](http://radshaperc.businesscatalyst.com/test)

Comment: You've got a linebreak inside a Liquid tag (between `if` and `globals`). That will break things.

Comment: Ahh! A little bit of tweaking and it now works perfectly! Thanks very much! One last thing, in BC, theres a quick tag for logging out `{module_logout}`, do you know if one exists for logging in? I don't see one. Just so I can do away with the href. Thanks again!

Comment: There is not. You need only link to the secured page; then the user will see the login form only if they are not logged in.

Comment: Ah I thought that might be the case. Thanks very much for your help!